# MVC 4 API API not loading when called by a program

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've created a MVC4 Web API application. When I connect to it in a web browser it works fine. It also works fine when my service connects, as long as I connect to it via a web browser first.  However, if I don't connect to it via a web browser, but simply have the service try to connect, the connection is timing out.

Any idea why it is not loading?

I am using .Net 4.5 in both applications.

My connection code looks like this:

```
var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(url) };

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); 

var response = Client.GetAsync("version/current").Result;
```

This last line is where I get the `TaskCanceledException` (after about 4 minutes).  Again, once the site is loaded up, this call works fine.

Comment: Have you tried using Fiddler2 for it? It may will tell you what is wrong. Generally, sounds like you have some initialization issue. Are Browser and in-code calls routed to the same Action? It is easy to debug.

Comment: They make the same call.  Fiddler2 does not show anything for the application calls, even when it is working.  It seems if I use "localhost" for the in-code calls it works.  Just not if I use the machine name.  Since I need to be able to call this remotely, I need to see if a remote call is different.  If so, I can use the localhost for same box and machine name for remote calls.

Comment: OK.  If I run the program as a logged on user, it works fine.  Seems there is something with running as a service.

Comment: windows service? Your win service should also run under some user account. Create that user with all the privileges and set your service to execute under that user credentials.